# ie "webpage has expired" on back button PHP session problem

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

On IE when user hits back button they get the classic IE "webpage has expired" message.

I have found that setting the following in my php.ini has solved this.

```
'session.cache_limiter=private'
```

However my problem now is when I send forms I include a PHP session value ($_SESSION['token']) in a hidden field. I then check this on the following page to see if token values match

```
echo "<form ......<input type='hidden' name='token' value='".$_SESSION['token']."' />";

/*on recieving page*/
if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']){/*ok matched*/}
else{/*THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS*/}
```

My problem is since adding this setting to my php.ini file I noticed when sending forms I get my custom page error as for some reason the $_SESSION['token'] value appears to change on the page receiving the form data thus making the if() statement return false? It's happening in all browsers now?

Here is my $_SESSION['token'] code (NOTE when sending my form it lands in the else() but value changes of $_SESSION['token'] something to do with cache perhaps not retaining my $_SESSION values?

```
session_start()
if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
            $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token; /*have to put current session token into this variable for hidden field in <form>*/
            $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
}
else
{
            /*if token set ie user press back button on browser*/
            $token_age = time() - $_SESSION['token_time'];
            if ($token_age > 1200)
            {
                        /* More than 20 minutes has passed - regenerate. Do this so more likely wont timeout when user taking long time on <form> and token may not get refreshed before time limit*/
                        $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
                        $_SESSION['token'] = $token; /*have to put current session token into this variable for hidden field in <form>*/
                        $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
            }

}
```

If any use heres my other php.ini session settings

```
session.cache_limiter=private
session.cookie_secure=1 ;my wholes site is SSL
session.cookie_httponly=1
session.save_path = /tmp ;directory to store sessions
session.save_handler = files
session.cookie_lifetime = 0 ;persistence cookie dies after browser closed
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

Let me just clear something up guys, the reason this whole problem occurs is using the 'session.cache_limiter=private'. If I take this out theres no problem except I get a message in IE when hitting back button on a form page saying "Webpage expired". Is there any suggestions how to avoid that message occuring in IE when hitting the back button?

Comment: How about observing your $token_age?

Comment: You are using `session.cookie_secure=1`. Is your site on a [secure (https) server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)? Try turning that one off?

Comment: Yes I have but its not getting into that if(). Just in the else().  
its something to do with that setting session.cache_limiter=private as without it it works but I get "webpage expired message" in IE if I take it out. I am missing something I think as cache appears to get wiped out on each page. Something to do with session.cache_expire I think?

Comment: My whole site is SSL, have now mentioned that in previous question.

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP headers?

Comment: Not sure how or What to look for?

Comment: One other thing, are you using any ajax on the page? If you do, you should check if there is a script called, that clears the session. Try putting any ajax request out, for a test.

Comment: For the headers you can do that directly with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php from a different script var_exporting the result. There you can see what kind of caching does the server suggest to the browser.

Comment: Let me just clear something up, the reason this whole problem occurs is using the 'session.cache_limiter=private'. If I take this out theres no problem except I get a message in IE when hitting back button on a form page saying "Webpage expired". Is there any suggestions how to avoid that message occuring in IE when hitting the back button?

Comment: I tried using your code on my server (including session settings in php.ini). Didn't have any problems. Everything worked fine just as expected... Not helping, but may be noteworthy...

Comment: That means that the code is OK. It's a server thing than. PHP or Apache/IIS/... settings.

Comment: Or the error occurs in another part of the code that we don't see here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "must-revalidate");

Comment: Can I put that in my php.ini like 'session.cache_limiter=must-revalidate' or does it have to be in PHP script using ini_set() ?

Comment: Is that a supported option? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: Just tried the ini_set(‘session.cache_limiter’, ‘must-revalidate’); in my PHP code thats causing the same problem

Comment: Noticed with the ini_set these error messages 02-Jun-2011 07:11:38] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘session - assumed '‘session' in ...
[02-Jun-2011 07:11:38] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant cache_limiter’ - assumed 'cache_limiter’' in ....
[02-Jun-2011 07:11:38] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘must - assumed '‘must' in ....
[02-Jun-2011 07:11:38] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant revalidate’ - assumed 'revalidate’' in ....

Comment: Those error messages result from the illegal quotemarks in the statement above. Try replacing them manually with ' or ".

Comment: You can put it in your php.ini without problems.

Comment: Thanks it has worked guys using the ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "must-revalidate"); replaced ' with " and did the job. How can I put this in my php.ini file now and this is best answer?

Comment: 'session.cache_limiter=must-revalidate'

Comment: Thanks problem solved guess it was =must-revalidate rather than =private that was my problem. Thanks @Anze Jarni and @BlaM for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is that in HTML code?

```
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='".$_SESSION['token']."' />
```

If yes, try:

```
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?PHP echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>' />
```

:)

---

I never was too happy with the PHP built-in session functionality. Too many problems for me...

Are you initializing session handling with `session_start()`?

Are you sure that sessions are using cookies - not any Query-String / POST fields? (Check the generated HTML code in the browser).

Comment: yes I do use session_start() forgot to paste it in my code provided, I have amended my previous question added some more settings which may be causing problems?

Comment: Nope I am obviously echoing HTML <form> in PHP have amended previous question code again.

Comment: its something to do with that setting session.cache_limiter=private as without it it works but I get "webpage expired message" in IE if I take it out. I am missing something I think as cache appears to get wiped out on each page. Something to do with session.cache_expire I think?